# iOS: executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I developed an application targeted for iPhone and it uses CoreData. All is working ok when  I run it on the simulator, but when I run it on the device I'm getting the following error:

`"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'"`

I have specified and defined an entity in my code as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *select = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"NewsStand" inManagedObjectContext:[CDHelper sharedCDHelper].managedObjectContext];
[select setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *results = [[[CDHelper sharedCDHelper].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:select error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

The error occurs when I execute the fetch to show in a tableView what has stored the DB.

I also have defined a managedObjectModel:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
 {
if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"newsStandModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you load the managed object model what do you specify as the model file name? (something `.mom`).

The simulator is not case sensitive, the device *is*. i.e.

if the file is called `MyModel.mom` then

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mymodel" type:@"mom"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithString:string];
myModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

works on the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: Hi @deamWombourne, I just added a code where I defined the managedObejectModel and I double checked that the name was spelled correctly. Any new thoughts about this? thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you get if you put `NSLog(@"url : %@", modelURL);` - do you get the correct URL for your model or do you get nil?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you spelled the entity name correctly?  Are you sure the managed object context's managed object model has an entity with that name?  Either of those things could cause `+entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` to return `nil`, which is almost definitely your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setter method from `CoraData` ... Just do something like this...

On your `CustomCoreDataManager.m`

```
#import "ObjectiveRecord.h" 

call init method like this

-(instancetype)init {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

[[CoreDataManager sharedManager] setModelName:@"YourModelName"]; }

return self; }
```

Hope this helps to someone...